# Find the area of the shaded section on a square.

Tags: circles, area

In the diagram,the curved paths are arcs of circles centered at vertices $A$ and $B$ of a square of side $6$. Find the area of the shaded section $BCD$.

I've been stuck on this problem for days. I have tried to get the shaded section by puzzling with the figures but failed. I've tried to add more lines to get a set of equations but that failed. But I still want to be able to solve it by myself so if you guys can give me  only hints, that would be best.
[image]

Comment: One possible way should be splitting the area with the normal on BC through A.

Comment: Are you familiar with integrals?

Comment: Since you can calculate the area of BCA, it suffices to compute BDA and subtract. Hint: BDA is _almost_ a sector of the circle centered on A, but DA is curved. Similarly, it's almost a sector of the circle centered on B. If you computed the area of the _triangle_ ΔBDA, as well as the sectors, how would that help you?

Comment: Here’s another hint. http://imgur.com/5NHedVO The pink area and the green area in this picture are “segments” of a circle or radius 6. You can find their areas if you can figure out the angle of the arc they span. Then the area you want is a triangle (one side is the radius of a circle, and you can probably figure out the angles) plus the green segment plus half the pink segment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a hint with double integrals. Split the area in two:

[image]

Then

\begin{align}
S_{CBED}&=
S_{CED}+S_{CBE}
=
\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\int_{f_2(x)}^{f_1(x)} dy dx
+
\int_{x_2}^{x_3}\int_{f_3(x)}^{f_1(x)} dy dx
\end{align}
where

\begin{align}
f_1(x)&=\sqrt{6^2-(x-6)^2},
\\
f_2(x)&=6-\sqrt{6^2-(x-6)^2},
\\
f_3(x)&=x,
\\
x_1&=6-3\sqrt{3},
\\
x_2&=6-3\sqrt{2},
\\
x_3&=6.
\end{align}

$S_{CBED}=\tfrac{15}{2}\pi-9\sqrt{3}\approx 7.97348763$.

Another way to split the area:

[image]

suggests a geometric solution as a sum 
of the sector $BCD$ and a difference
between the sector $ABD$ and $\triangle ABD$.

$\triangle ABD$ is equilateral (why?), so

\begin{align}
S_1&=\tfrac12 \cdot 36(\tfrac\pi3-\tfrac\pi4)=\tfrac32 \pi
\\
S_2&=\tfrac12 \cdot 36\tfrac\pi3=6\pi
\\
S_3&=9\sqrt3
\end{align}

And the answer is $\tfrac{15}2\pi-9\sqrt3$, as above.

Comment: thank you for showing both methods.